# Marketing Developer Platform access request rejected

Tags: linkedin-api

Not so far ago I've requested a "Marketing Developer Platform" product acces for my LinkedIn application. After few days from request I got "declined" status without any explanation over my email. Is there any chance to get any details about it? And some clues how to successfully pass it?

Best regards,
Lukasz

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a customer support question.

Comment: I've asked this question on linkedin forums, they've forwarded me here ...

Comment: any updates? we're having the same issues

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer service question, not a software development question.